# C# - Curved line between 2 points

Tags: c#, drawing, line

I have 2 sets of parallel and when their angles differ, I end up with a intersection on one end, and an open gap on the other.  I have taken care of the interesection, by setting the endPoint of line1 to the same as the starting point for line2. Like so...

[image]

This is the code I have so far for adding the lines....

```
for (int i: 0; i < myLines.size() ; i++) {
   Line myLine = checkforInterection( myLines, i);
   myCanvas.Children.Add(myLine);
   myCanvas.Children.Add(createParallel(myLine));
}
```

I would like to close the gap on the rightHand side by having a **curved** line that can span the distance.  What is the best way of going about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [BezierSegment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.beziersegment.aspx) to obtain a smooth curve. The start and end points should be the start and end points of the straight line. The control point may require some experimentation to get looking like you want it to, since that's more of a preference, but setting the control point to the projected intersection of the two lines the curve is attached to would make a good starting point. If you do want to tweak it after that, you should move it along the line from the projected intersection to the actual intersection of the two lines on the left.

For clarity:

[image: Reference picture]

Start off with the start and end points at the green dots. Start off with the control point at the intersection of the red line, and, if you want to adjust it, move it along the blue line to keep a symmetric curve.

Note: using the intersection of the red lines will give you a perfectly smooth transition; other points won't.